# NGINX: Retrive cookie value given cookie name stored in $cookiename

Tags: nginx, cookies, configuration, nginx-location

I understand that nginx provides a nice embedded variable

```
$cookie_<name_of_cookie>
```

However, I have a variable, say $cookiename, which contains the name of the cookie I'm interested in. How do I extract the corresponding cookie value from $http_cookie?

For example, $http_cookie is "key1=abc,key2=def". I have $cookiename = "key1". I would like to get "abc".

Comment: You could do this with Lua. With some limitations you could do this with `map`. But I can’t imagine any reason to do this. Why do you want it?

Comment: I extract $cookiename from the URL path, say /<$cookie_name>/abc. The incoming request contains the following cookie key and value: <$cookie_name>:"cookie_value". I would like to use nginx to rename the cookie field to "token":"cookie_value".